# Should I use a smart pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, smart-pointers

I have a class like the following:

```
class node
{
public:

     node* parent;
     std::list<node*> children;
};
```

Should I use a smart pointer instead of raw pointers? Why? If yes, what kind of smart pointer?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Always use a smart pointer wherever you own resources (memory, files etc). Owning them manually is *extremely* error prone and violates *many* good practices, like [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Which one to use depends on what ownership semantics you need. `unique_ptr` is best for single ownership, and `shared_ptr` shared ownership.

As children do not own their parents, a raw parent pointer is fine. However, if the parents own their children, `unique_ptr` works best here.

It's also notable that *what on earth*, a linked list of pointers? That makes no sense. Why not a linked list of values?

Comment: The problem here is that it is highly unlikely that `node` owns any resources.  In this case, ownership probably belongs in the containing class (`Tree` or whatever), even if it doesn't contain any direct pointers to the object.  Use of `unique_ptr` here, of course, is completely wrong, and `shared_ptr` doesn't work unless you throw in some `weak_ptr`, which results in code which is less reliable and more complex than if you do the thing correctly.

Comment: @JamesKanze: The resources of, say... the memory of the child nodes? And it's quite impossible for a `unique_ptr` based version of this structure to be less reliable or more complex than the raw pointer based version. In fact, `unique_ptr` is practically *the definition* of reliable and simple. Perhaps you should expand on exactly why you think the smart pointer version would be worse than the raw pointer version.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain why requiring several different pointer types and adding unnecessary complexity is an improvement.  Using smart pointers here is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @JamesKanze: No problem. For one, you, the implementer, no longer have to manually delete the nodes. This *guarantees* that you cannot double delete them, or forget to delete them, and also guarantees exception safety. And you get it for *removing* all that code that would otherwise do deletion. So it reduces code size and guarantees safety. That sounds like a win in every way I can imagine to me. As for different pointer types, well, in C++, you use different types to do different jobs. That's a necessary fact of life. The syntax clearly indicates what is what.

Comment: Using `unique_ptr` almost guarantees dangling pointers, and using `shared_ptr` guarantees memory leaks unless you also use `weak_ptr` (and dangling pointers if you don't).  Doing the right thing explicitly is far simpler than trying to second guess tools which were designed for other purposes.

Comment: @JamesKanze: `unique_ptr` introduces no more dangling pointers than `delete` does. And `shared_ptr` *only* introduces memory leaks when there are reference cycles- something all good designs *very rarely* have, and even very bad designs very rarely have- and no more dangling pointers than `delete`.

Comment: @JamesKanze _`Using unique_ptr almost guarantees dangling pointers`_ - I'm having trouble seeing what you mean. Could you point to an example?

Comment: @JamesKanze: I'd say that raw pointers are completely the wrong choice for the child nodes; I'd rather not have to do an exception-safety dance to add one to the collection. As DeadMG says, a `list` of values would work here, so there's no need for smart pointers at all. Unless the children are polymorphic, in which case `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @DomagojPandža and where is the dangling pointer? Right there you have a nice neat packaged automatic objects created dynamically. (yes, I am aware of the 'comedy' of the response)

Comment: @MikeSeymour the children are polymorphic, but i think it's better `std::shared_ptr`, why do you propose `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: @gliderkite: You show no indication that sharing the ownership is necessary.

Comment: @gliderkite: Use `unique_ptr` if the object has a single owner (which is implied by the tree-like parent/child heirarchy); it's a simple, uncopyable pointer that's difficult to make mistakes with, and is as efficient as a raw pointer. Use `shared_ptr` if you want to share ownership, and be very careful with circular dependencies since they can easily lead to memory leaks, or if you're using an old-school compiler that doesn't support `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour And use what if the ownership pattern doesn't follow either of those very restrictive rules (which is the usual case, and the case in the OP's example)?

Comment: The dangling pointer is, of course, the raw pointers you have left when `unique_ptr` deletes your object.  Raw pointers that were necessary because you need to access the object.  You detach a subtree, and suddenly all pointers into it are dangling.  Before you get the chance to perhaps attach it elsewhere, or do anything else with it.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I'm not sure if I'm clear about what you're suggesting.  If the idea is to have all of the nodes in a separate container, contained in `Tree`, and to use `unique_ptr` in this container if the nodes are polymorphic (a node pool, so to speak), that could be reasonable in certain cases (although I've not found much need for it).  The pointers _in_ the nodes should always be raw pointers, however.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I'm not sure if I'm clear about what you're suggesting.  If the idea is to have all of the nodes in a separate container, contained in `Tree`, and to use `unique_ptr` in this container if the nodes are polymorphic (a node pool, so to speak), that could be reasonable in certain cases (although I've not found much need for it).  The pointers _in_ the nodes should always be raw pointers, however.

Comment: @JamesKanze: There are no additional dangling pointers with unique ptr. Consider a function like `template<typename T> void f(T* p) { delete p; }`. Do you consider that `f(p)` leaks more than `delete p;`? Of course not. So why is it any different if, instead of `f`, I have `~unique_ptr`? It was *your* choice as to when to erase that item and delete the pointer, and that choice occurs at exactly the same time as when you would otherwise have called `delete ptr;` if you were manually managing it, meaning that it is impossible to create additional dangling pointers.

Comment: @DeadMG In trivial cases, `unique_ptr` will work.  But of course, in trivial cases, it doesn't really buy you much.  In more complex cases, it will result in either dangling pointers or empty `unique_ptr` where they shouldn't be empty.  At some point, objects other than the parent node need to have a pointer to the node.  If that pointer is a `unique_ptr`, then the pointer in the parent is suddenly empty.  And if it is a raw pointer, then changing the topology of the tree will cause it to dangle.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Well, you could simply use `std::move` to change the tree and not delete the object.

Comment: @DeadMG You can do a lot of things which make the code harder to read and to understand.  I like the KISS principle---in this case, it means having the tree manage the lifetime of the nodes, possibly with a pool of nodes (in the case of very large trees, where nodes come and go), or by doing nothing (in the case where the tree _is_ the program data, and should live as long as the program; e.g. a parse tree in a compiler front end).

Comment: @James : Manual memory management is the opposite of 'simple'.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I've no idea where you got the impression that I'm suggesting some kind of "node pool". I'm simply inferring that each node owns its children, and suggesting that it manages them with unique pointers (since polymorphism rules out direct containment within the node's container). That saves the trouble of writing a destructor, handling failure to insert into the container, and avoiding accidental ownership sharing, all of which are necessary with manual management. If there is a strange ownership model necessitating manual management, then the question makes no mention of it.

Comment: @ildjarn There's no real complexity here: in the case of a tree, the owner of the nodes is obvious.  Smart pointers introduce any number of additional constraints, which make the resulting code more complex.

Comment: @MikeSeymour You mentionned something about all of the nodes being in a list.  Having a node "own" its children isn't a good solution in general, since it fails when you start reorganizing the tree, moving nodes from one parent to the next.

Comment: @JamesKanze: The list is the one in the question: `std::list<node*> children`. My assumption was that the OP intended to use this to manage the children, otherwise he wouldn't be asking whether or not to use smart pointers. Given that, `unique_ptr` is the right answer. If you do need to reorganise the tree, then it's a simple case of moving it from one set of children to another - I've no idea why you think that "fails". If you think a different ownership model is more appropriate, then perhaps you should write an answer that explains *why* smart pointers "don't work" and "should be avoided".

Comment: @MikeSeymour Well, the main reason is simply experience.  But the use case where `unique_ptr` doesn't work seems so obvious, I'm surprised anyone questions it.  I outlined it above: as soon as you need to access the nodes from outside the parent (which is almost always the case), you have problems.  And no one has yet been able to show the slightest advantage of using a smart pointer here; as is often the case, the smart pointer is presented as a silver bullet, when (at least in this case), it creates more problems than it solves.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I completely fail to see how using `unique_ptr` leads to dangling pointers in any way that using raw pointers wouldn't, despite all your cryptic hints that its both obvious and inevitable. The advantages of managing objects with `unique_ptr` over ad-hoc `delete` expressions are as I said above: no need to write a destructor, no need for a `try...catch` dance to put them in the container, and no danger of accidentally copying or losing a pointer that's supposed to represent ownership of an object. These are common problems with raw pointers, which `unique_ptr` solves completely.

Comment: @JamesKanze: And as I said, if you have a compelling reason for avoiding `unique_ptr`, please explain in an answer. Repeating the same vague arguments over and over again in comments is getting rather tedious.

Comment: @MikeSeymour There is more than one pointer to each node.  Not just in the tree; when traversing the tree, you will inevitably have additional pointers outside the tree.  `unique_ptr` deletes without taking those pointers into account.  In which case, they dangle.  (The obvious use case is if you're moving things around in the tree.  You remove the node from one parent, to attach it to another parent.  Ooops, it's been deleted.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: So don't "remove the node from one parent, to attach it to another parent"; move the pointer instead. Any other pointers to the node remain valid. The only reason to delete the node is to remove it from the tree, in which case any references to it are invalidated anyway (unless you need a more complicated scheme, but there's no indication of that here). I'm sorry, but I really can't see any more to your argument than "don't use smart pointers because, if you do the wrong things with them, the wrong things will happen"; which can be applied to any practice whatsoever.

Comment: @MikeSeymour But that's not my argument against smart pointers here.  My argument is that the introduce additional complexity, and introduce additional dangers that weren't there previously.  If you use `unique_ptr`, for example, you must implement a very special, non-intuitive protocol for rearranging the nodes in the tree.  If it really bought you something, it might be worth it, but in this case, cost and risk analysis comes down on the side of the raw pointer.

Comment: @JamesKanze: OK, this whole argument is just a difference of opinion of what constitutes "complexity" and "intuition". I'll stick to automatic, exception-safe memory management and well-defined transferable ownership semantics (which to me are entirely simple, intuitive and non-special); you stick to manual pointer-juggling if you like. Sorry to have carried on so long - from your repeated vague hints of danger, I thought you might know of a genuine problem with using `unique_ptr`, which is why I kept asking you to elaborate.

Answer (score 5):

It is always a good idea to use smart pointers, but beware of loops of references.

```
class node
{
public:
     std::weak_ptr<node> parent;
     std::list< std::shared_ptr<node> > children;
};
```

That's why there is the `weak_ptr` in the first place. Note that they are not so smart to detect the loops, you have to do it manually, and break them by using `weak_ptr`s.

Comment: There's no need for the parent pointer to be a non-raw pointer.

Comment: @DeadMG Unless he needs to create a `shared_ptr` from it at some time.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Possible, but not particularly likely, and there is no expressed need for shared ownership here, so unique ownership and a raw pointer is the simplest design.

Comment: In other words, use smart pointers to make the code more obfuscated and less reliable than if you'd used raw pointers.  Any time you have to use `weak_ptr`, it's a good bet that `shared_ptr` was not a good design decision.  And anytime you mix `shared_ptr` and raw pointers (including `this`), you're asking for trouble.  _If_ some sort of reference counting is appropriate (which is rarely the case, and never the case when dealing with graph-like structures), and you need raw pointers as well (like `this`), then use `intrusive_ptr`, not `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I agree that resorting to `weak_ptr` is usually a bad thing, but I don't see at all how using smart pointers in this case is more obfuscated or less reliable than the raw pointer version. The smart pointer version is identical in every respect, except it guarantees protection from double deletes, memory leaks, and other bad behaviours which raw pointer based code exhibits all the time.

Comment: @DeadMG Mixing pointer types rapidly becomes very confusing.  `unique_ptr` will end up being a sure source of errors here, either because capture will be too late (resulting in a memory leak) or too early (resulting in a pointer being invalidated when it shouldn't be).

Comment: @DeadMG The smart pointer version is identical, except that it results in confusion surrounding the different types of pointers, and additional errors due to this confusion.  (Smart pointers may be appropriate when constructing the nodes, releasing the pointer once the node is firmly in the tree.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: It is impossible to capture it too late. The simple `unique_ptr<T> x(new T(...))` scenario is quite bulletproof. Even for function arguments, there's the usual evaluation order hilarity, and the Standard kindly left out `make_unique` (accepted as a defect), but you can write your own which is guaranteed correct even in that scenario. As for too early, the `unique_ptr` will not release until you, the programmer, delete it. This occurs at the exact identical time as simply removing the pointer from the list and then deleting it.

Comment: As for pointer confusions, nobody who cannot tell the difference between `shared_ptr<T>`, `unique_ptr<T>`, and `T*` should really be coding production C++. Not to mention that the compiler can handily protect you from *almost* all usage errors of these pointers- not something you can say of raw pointers.

Comment: @DeadMG It's impossible to capture too late if you have a policy of capturing too early.  Moving pointers from one node to the next, for example, becomes more complicated when smart pointers are used, and you also have issues concerning the owner when creating a new node; depending on the logic, it could easily make sense to finish filling the data elements _after_ having moved it into the tree.

Comment: @JamesKanze: More complicated? It's a dead simple insertion for `shared_ptr` - much simpler than the raw pointer version, of course- and a simple `std::move` for `unique_ptr`. There's no significant complexity there. As for filling it after moving it into the tree, then ... just give out a non-owning reference on insertion. This is exactly the behaviour of Standard containers like `std::map`, and they function just fine.

Answer (score -2):

Absolutely not.  The usual smart pointers don't work with graph-like
structures, and should be avoided.  In this case, you have a tree, and
there's no problem handling all of the deletions (and allocations) from
the tree object itself.

Comment: Strict hierarchical graphs can be handled fine by `std::unique_ptr`, and any DAG can work fine with `std::shared_ptr`. As the structure in the question is a strict hierarchy, there is no reason to believe that either Standard smart pointer would not be perfectly correct.

Comment: @DeadMG With a bit of effort, you can manage anything.  In this case, using `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` require significantly more effort, and are considerably more error prone, than just handling all memory management in the containing `Tree` class.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I don't know what effort you have in mind, but last time I checked, having the `std::list` destruct the value type it contains for you was *free*.

Comment: @DeadMG The effort of managing several different types of pointers, and being sure that you use the right one in each context.

Comment: @JamesKanze: There are only *three* kinds of pointers you might care to need (on a regular basis). The decision of when to use which one is trivial, and *identical* to the decision of when you use `delete`. The only difference is that the smart pointer can implement that decision much more reliably. If you don't know when to delete an object, you have a bigger problem than what type you're using today. If you do, then you already know what smart pointer to use.

Comment: @DeadMG There is only one kind of pointer you care about on a regular basis: a raw pointer.  The smart pointers are designed to solve particular problems; none is appropriate for general use.  The most widespread smart pointers (e.g. `shared_ptr`) all have serious flaws when you try to use them generally.

Comment: @JamesKanze: "Object Y is responsible for destructing Object Z, for a generic definition of "destruct"" is a pretty general problem. Oh, just in case you were curious, I actually did not downvote your answer.

Comment: @DeadMG Yes.  In this case, `Tree` is responsible for destructing its nodes.  Even those to which it doesn't have pointer.  I've actually tried making systematic use of smart pointers in real applications.  All I got for it were cycles and memory leaks.  (And I don't worry about the down votes.  It's quite frequent here that incorrect answers get tons of upvotes, so why shouldn't a correct one get a down vote?)